# redirect ajax call in java and jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, response.redirect

I am using jsp and jquery...and struts.I have a problem understanding the redirect to login page for ajax request.I tried to see request on browser on XHR tab and it gives me 302 status code in header.I am not able to comprehend how do i redirect.
My approach
1)The application has a function which checks if the user is signed in or not and has function to redirect to login url.
2)Else do some other processing.

How do I come back to same page after login.Is there any way?.....Also for redirecting on server side i am using Response.redirect()...Can someone explain how to catch response from server?...

```
function buttonpress(param1,param2)
{
$.ajax({
type:"GET",
data:{
X:param1,
Y:param2,
},
url:"/application",
success:function()
{
alert("success message");
}
error:function()
{
alert("error message")
}

});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `data` parameter passed to the ajax `success()` callback. If a `302` was issued, the target URL would be available at `data.redirect`.

```
function buttonpress(param1,param2)
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      X:param1,
      Y:param2,
    },
    url: "/application",
    success: function(data, status)
    {
      if (data.redirect) {
        window.location.href = data.redirect;
      } else {
        alert("success message");
      }
    },
    error:function()
    {
      alert("error message")
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: i tried but still giving the same error..but if pass the parameters that is X and Y as query params...say eg:www.abc.com/application?X=1&Y=2.....it is taking me to sign in page.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
function buttonpress(param1,param2)
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      X:param1,
      Y:param2,
    },
    url: "/application",
    success: function(data)
    {
      var flag = data.trim();
      if (flag) {
         // success code
      } else {
         window.location.href = '/logout.do';
      }
    }        
  });
}
```